# Setting hostname of a Surge CNAME record to @ on GoDaddy

Tags: deployment, cname, surge.sh

I'm trying to deploy my portfolio to my domain www.dillonbartkus.com with Surge.

The instructions are as follows:

[image: instructions]

I'm using a GoDaddy domain that I bought through Google Suite.

In the picture it shows a CNAME record with a hostname of `www` and `@` and a value of `na-west1.surge.sh`. When I try to do this in my DNS records, I can do the CNAME with `www` for the name, but when I try to do the `@` I get an error that says 'Enter your host name as "@", "sub-domain" '.

I have tried all different syntax for this, but it won't go through.

[image: error]

How do I add / edit the other to include @ ?

Comment: Off-topic. Try https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must delete all `A` & `CNAME` records on GoDaddy first, then follow the [Surge documentation](https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-custom-domain). GoDaddy only allows a `CNAME` `www` record to be added, not `@`.

The documentation states you should replace the `CNAME` `@` (apex domain) record with an `A` `@` record using Surge's IP.

Thus, on GoDaddy you must delete all existing `A` & `CNAME` records and add the following two records following a `Type` : `Name` : `Value` format:

`CNAME`: `www` : `na-west1.surge.sh`

`A` : `@` : `45.55.110.124`

This had my domain resolving within 5 minutes.

https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/domain-DNS-with-surge-sh/td-p/24075