# Adding GoDaddy Domain Name to Surge

Tags: reactjs, godaddy-api, surge.sh

I have followed the [Surge documentation](https://surge.sh/help/adding-a-custom-domain)

As well as the past question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620166/setting-hostname-of-a-surge-cname-record-to-on-godaddy)

However, when I visit my web page after 2-3 hours, it is still not able to be found: http://mini-interface.com/.

I have attached the successful publishing message using surge CLI on terminal and also my GoDaddy DNS Management settings.

[image: DNS Management Settings GoDaddy]
[image: successful publishing using surge on terminal]

Comment: I just visited the link from the description and it seems to me that your web page is up and running, isn't it? If you managed to resolve the issue, would you share the answer to your question?

Comment: Hello Adrian, yes! I believe I solved it. However, it's now some time ago and I can't remember what I did:(